# Under these declarations, what types are the following expressions and are they correct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member-variables

```
struct place 

{

    char name[80+1];
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
};

struct node

{

    struct place city;
    struct node *next;

};

struct node *head;


head
head -> city
head -> next
head -> city -> name
head -> next ->city.name
```

These kinds of tasks always make me lose points on exams, anyone kind enough to explain? It's asking about what types the variables mentioned are, and I guess stuff like `head` are simply a pointer towards the value of entire structure `node`?

Comment: Yes, basically you're right. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Are there any wrong expression in those 5 lines below the code, and why are they wrong?

Comment: `head -> city -> name` doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the purpose of SO is not to explain basic tenets of `c` but to help solve specific problems with code.

Answer (score 1):

In the later snippet at the later part,

```
head -> city -> name
```

is wrong, because, `city` is not a pointer type. You need to use the dot operator (`.`) to access a member of a non-pointer structure variable. Just the way you've used it in

```
head -> next ->city.name
```

Other than that, syntactically, the snippets appear fine.

Just to add, as a basic sanity, you should be checking for non-`NULL`-ity of a pointer before de-referencing to avoid invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).